# Thin space in SQL Server / use Unicode code

Tags: sql-server

I would like to write an update query like this one:

```
update vwArticlesPerm
set libelle = replace(libelle, '"', ??? +'in')
where libelle like '%[0-9]"%'
```

where `???` is to be replaced by a [Thin space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_space).
Any clue on how to type that in SSMS or which code to use with CHAR() ?
(and generally, how to enter any Unicode character for which I have a code)

Comment: For Unicode characters use `NCHAR(code)` I.e. here `select nchar(0x2009)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Unicode characters use `NCHAR(code)` I.e. here `select nchar(0x2009)`

This will work for all `NCHAR` and `NVARCHAR` fields and variables, but for `CHAR` or `VARCHAR`, will only work for fields where thin space is included in the character set.

Answer (score 0):

As I found [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2009/index.htm), unicode for thin space is U2009. To insert unicode in SQL Query, please use:

```
update vwArticlesPerm
set libelle = replace(libelle, '"', nchar(0x2009) +'in')
where libelle like '%[0-9]"%'
```

Comment: I think you  need to remove the U from 0xU2009

Comment: Yes, indeed my friend :)